# Ожидание завершения AsyncTask без блокировки основного UI потока

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Нужно дождаться завершения AsyncTask без блокировки основного потока для того, чтобы невозможно было выйти из Activity, нажав Back.

Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Заведите себе флаг типа `boolean`, который ставьте поумолчанию в `false`, а в `onPostExecute()` `AsyncTask` ставльте его в true, и переопределите `onBackPressed` у `Activity`, чтобы пока флаг `!= true`, ничего не делать.